# Reading a binary file in C and accessing a range of bits

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

I have the following C code, that reads a binary file and outputs the file in big endian binary format

Now I have a program counter that begins at 0 and reads each instruction and increments the program counter by 4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INSTRUCTION_SIZE 4
#define INSTR_MEM_SIZE 1024
#define DATA_MEM_SIZE 1024
#define VR_SIZE 256
#define HEAP_BANKS 128
#define BANK_SIZE 64
#define NUM_REGS  32

unsigned char instruction_memory[INSTR_MEM_SIZE];
unsigned char data_memory[DATA_MEM_SIZE];
unsigned char virtual_machine_memory[VR_SIZE];
unsigned char heap_memory[HEAP_BANKS][BANK_SIZE];
int program_counter = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    char *filename = "mHbar.mi";
    unsigned char buffer[INSTRUCTION_SIZE];
    int i, j;
    long filesize;

    file = fopen("examples/printing_h/printing_h.mi", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    for (i = 0; i < filesize; i += INSTRUCTION_SIZE) {
        // read a single instruction
        fread(buffer, 1, INSTRUCTION_SIZE, file);

        program_counter += INSTRUCTION_SIZE;

        uint  instructionValue = 0;

        for (j = INSTRUCTION_SIZE - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            // convert the hex value to binary
            unsigned char hex = buffer[j];
            for (int k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                instructionValue = (hex >> k) & 1;
                printf("%d",instructionValue);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // close the file
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Now this code outputs the instruction value which is in binary

```
`01111111111100000000000100010011
 00000000110000000000000011101111
00000000000000000001011110110111
10000000000001111000011000100011
00000000000000000001011110110111
00000100100000000000011100010011
 10000000111001111000000000100011
00000000000000000000010100010011
 00000000000000001000000001100111`
```

Now when the program counter is 0 it points to the first instruction that is

01111111111100000000000100010011

I wish to extract a operational code 0010011 and assign it to a variable (the last 7 bits)

I also wish to check if that a specific opcode exists in a instruction, if it does I want to print to std for now lets just print "A specific op code is found"

Finally how would I go about extract specific bits from the instruction for example, lets say I want the first 5 bits or the last 7 bits

How would I go about doing this?

Right now I have not tried anything, and am stumped as to how to approach this problem, for example the main issue I am having is that how do i manipulate each instruction, since I am not really storing it in anything

I am currently storing each instruction in an instruction array of size 1024 bytes.

Comment: Two (unrelated) things: First always check what `fread` returns. It could fail for any number of reasons. Secondly, switch the order of the sizes. With your current order, uoi might actually read *less* than `INSTRUCTION_SIZE`.

Comment: As for your problem, what do you know about the bitwise operations? You are using masking with the `&` operation in the code you show, so you must know something about it? And you have the the bytes of the "instruction", which means you can very easily get a specific byte and then use masking to get the seven bits you want.

Comment: And a few tips: Read into an `uint32_t` variable instead of using bytes. Do byte- and word-swap if the byte-order in the file is not the same as on your system. Then use plain bit masking and shifting to get the parts you need. into a structure. Optionally it might be possible to use a (packed and non-reordered) bittfield structure, and use it directly both for reading and getting the individual values. The bitfield solution depends very much on compiler support though, most binary code interpreters or parsers uses plain ints and bitwise operations.